# Sublime text snippet error - 'No content for snippet'

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, code-snippets

I have problem with some of my snippet. I have this error:

> No content fort snippet
>   Packages/User/boot_champs/autocomplete.sublime-snippet

There is the snippet:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Client : </label>
    <div class="input-group" id="">
        <input type="hidden"  name="DATA[XXXXX]" id="XXXXX" value="<?php echo $XXXXX->XXXXX;?>" >
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="XXXXX" id="XXXXX" value="<?php echo $XXXXX->XXXXX; ?>" placeholder="Taper des caractéres ou flêche du bas">
        <span class="input-group-addon" onClick="javascript:$('#XXXX_id').val('0');$('#XXXXX_libelle').val('');$('#XXXX_libelle').focus();" >
            <i class="fa fa-times-circle" data-toggle="popover" title="Effacer la sélection" data-content="Cliquer sur la croix pour supprimer la donnée" data-placement="top"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>  
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>boot_champs_autocomplete</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html.basic</scope>
    <description>[Boot] Champs autocomplete</description>
</snippet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$` character is a special character used in snippets to add fields or variables. So, you need to escape all your `$` characters in your snippet with the `\` key.

You can read it in [Sublime Text docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html):

> If you want to get a literal $, you have to escape it like this: \$.